# Am I calculating the limit properly without use of the Squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits

Consider the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (x^3sin(\frac{1}{x}))$. My textbook uses the Squeeze theorem to calculate the limit but can I do this as follows:

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (x^3sin(\frac{1}{x}))=\lim \limits_{x \to 0}(\frac{sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}x^2)=1*0=0$

?

I ask because I think this method is quicker than using the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: But the proof of the limit as $z\to 0$ of $\sin z/z$ is itself an application of the squeeze theorem so you are not really doing the exercise in a different way.

Comment: Just to be clear: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \sin(1/x)/(1/x)=0$, not $1$.

Comment: $\lim \limits_{x \to 0}\frac{sin\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final result is correct, but:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=\lim_{x \to 0}x\sin(1/x)=0
$$
because $\sin(1/x)$ is a bounded function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I thoughtlessly assumed that by analogy to the limit of sin(x)/x when x tends to zero, this would too be equal to 1. Now I think the reason that the textbook used the more lengthy method was that it hasn't covered L'Hospital's Rule yet (which is required to prove sin(1/x)/(1/x), I guess, so they opted for a lengthier method using absolute values and the Squeeze theorem.

Comment: Note that my answer does not use L'Hopital rule or squeeze.

Comment: I see now, I have looked only at the result - thanks again.

Comment: +1. But one can say that you are using the squeeze theorem indirectly, since "vanishish times bounded tends to zero" is usually proved by squeezing.